# How to combine two query's results into one cell?

Tags: oracle

I have two different queries in oracle, I was able to show these queries side by side with cross join, but I want to see them in the same cell.

First query :

```
SELECT 
           pa.attrb_an_value
           FROM
            piece_attrb pa
           WHERE
            pa.piece_num_id = 1056436 AND 
            pa.attrb_code = 'PSP')
```

> result : MCXTS

Second Query :

```
SELECT max(CAOSL.ATTRB_AN_VALUE)
             FROM config_attrb_of_so_line caosl,
                  so_piece sp
            WHERE sp.piece_num_id = 1056436
              AND sp.so_id = caosl.so_id
              AND sp.so_line_id = caosl.so_line_id
              and SP.IS_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
              AND CAOSL.ATTRB_CODE = 'GRS'
```

> Result : DC0

I want to see like that in cell:

> MCXTS - DC0

Comment: Oracle and mysql are two different rdbms products. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you are actually using!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate them, then.

```
WITH
   tab_1 (retval)
   AS
      -- first query
      (SELECT pa.attrb_an_value
         FROM piece_attrb pa
        WHERE     pa.piece_num_id = 1056436
              AND pa.attrb_code = 'PSP'),
   tab_2 (retval)
   AS
      -- second query
      (SELECT MAX (caosl.attrb_an_value)
         FROM config_attrb_of_so_line caosl, so_piece sp
        WHERE     sp.piece_num_id = 1056436
              AND sp.so_id = caosl.so_id
              AND sp.so_line_id = caosl.so_line_id
              AND sp.is_active_flag = 'Y'
              AND caosl.attrb_code = 'GRS')
-- final result
SELECT a.retval || ' - ' || b.retval as final_result
  FROM tab_1 a CROSS JOIN tab_2 b
```